# find with -regex and or pipe | not working

Tags: regex, find

Can someone tell me why the third command doesn't give the files a and b? (Using the default bash on my Mac)

```bash
bashs: bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
bash: touch a
bash: touch b
bash: find . -type f -regex ".*a"
./a
bash: find . -type f -regex ".*b"
./b
bash: find . -type f -regex ".*\(a\|b\)"
<no output>
```

Apparently Macs use the FreeBSD version of find. The above does work with the -E flag but it seems like the syntax is the ed-regex style and so this won't work without the -E flag unless someone knows something I don't. It would be good if someone could confirm this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find . -type f -regex '.\/\(a\|b\)'
```

Or

```
find . -type f -regex '.\/\(a\|b\).*'
```

for searching files like (a|b)....